# How to make a program start a first start up of the day?

Tags: linux, windows-8, autostart

Is there a way to make a program start when I log in, but only in first session. If I shut down and restart again in the same day, that program won't auto start. I am asking in both Windows and Linux.

I think that the only way is to write script, but I am seeking for a way to not to write.

Comment: What operating system.  How you would do this on Linux is entirely different compare to how you would do it on Windows.  I know on Windows if you were to shutdown, there is no way to tell if, you had already logged into the computer previously.

Comment: I use Netrunner. It bases on Kubuntu. I think in Linux you can write a script, but in Windows it is harder. I am seeking for a method that's not require to write script.

Comment: Outside of a script this isn't possible on Windows.

Comment: Easy or not (IMHO easy) to do a __script is the most convenient way__. Imagine that if you want to do only one execution of that program per day you need a program always running and checking for access to any executable, as an _antivirus_ can do on windows. It's a huge waste of resources. If you want to check only for the automatic execution at login time, a script with 2-3 lines of code will solve the problem. Please add the graphical environment under Linux, it matters. Note there's a difference between 1st login of the day and 1st login of the day from the last boot...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you can change this program yourself, the only way is to script. Luckily that is straightforward (on Windows, I assume you can do the same on Linux in a similar way):

```
:: Get date and remove / character
set d=%date:/=%
if exist "%TEMP%\%d%" goto :EOF
echo _ > "%TEMP%\%d%"
start program
```

**EDIT**

Right now I have ~30,000 file in my TEMP folder, on a system I don't use too much, so I wouldn't worry too much about 365 1-byte files over a year. Admittedly, these files still take a full block (4kB?), and maybe you're short of diskspace, so here is a second script that only uses a single file.

```
set today=%temp%\today
if exist "%today%" (
    find "%date%" "%today%"
    if errorlevel 0 goto :EOF
)

echo %date% > "%today%"
start program
```

Comment: I was going to comment that, after a year of running that, the user would have 365 temp files lying around.  But I tried it first.  (You didn't, did you?)  The `echo` command gives me `The system cannot find the path specified.`  I guess this is because `%date%` looks like "Wed 04/22/2015", and Windows treats `/`s in pathnames like ``\``s.  Filenames can't contain `/`s.

Comment: I actually did try, but on a dutch system which gives **wo 22-04-2015**. You can fix it by using **%date:/=%**

Comment: I thought about the 365 temp files you would have, and also figured a way around it (put the files in %temp%\subfolder, and remove everything from it after you check for the 'today file'), but that would only distract from the original question

Comment: @Scott so is it good to use now?

Comment: It still has the issue of stuffing your TEMP folder with hundreds of little files (with spaces in their names), but it looks like it should work.

Comment: thank you Berend. Sorry if this question looks stupid but how do I run this script? I paste it to Notepad and change the extension to exe, and run it at every startup but it doesn't work.

Comment: @Ooker Try to change the extension to **bat** or **cmd**. Also, don't forget to change the last line `start program` to whatever you need to start _your_ program

Comment: yeah, I know that I need to change the last line. I think this one should work.

Comment: it doesn't work. I have replaced `program` in the last line to `C:\"Program Files"\Anki\anki.exe` but the only thing appears when I start my computer is a DOS window, and it disappear immediately. When I type the command in cmd, the program does run.